# Page won't scroll on mobile, text bunched at the top of page

Tags: html, css

I've recently made my first website whilst learning HTML/CSS/Js/PhP over a couple of months.

When loading on a mobile device, one page in which I made a parallax scrolling header image will not scroll (horizontal nor vertical)?

I usually use "inspect element" to track bugs down, but as this happens on my mobile I can't figure it out - why is this happeneing?

The page is;

http://lcpdevelopment.flourishsales.co.uk/business-users.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove inline `style="overflow: hidden;"` from `<body>` and `<html>`

follow this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) and then you can debug mobile site on desktop.

Comment: there is no inline style in the .php file? I've just tried adding inline style "style="overflow: visible" and no result

Comment: right okay, added `style="overflow: visible !important;"` to both the body and html and it fixed it, still unsure on why it was reading an inline style of "hidden" otherwise, but it's fine now

Answer (score 0):

You have used min-width: 969px on different secitons of this page layout. Header image is missing this min-width. Add it to .homeSlide .bcg